# Why does vim call powershell surrounded by two single quotes?

Tags: microsoft-windows, external-command, shell

I'm attempting to use powershell from gvim, and when I do...I set:

```
:set shellcmdflag=-NoProfile\ -NoLogo\ -ExecutionPolicy\ RemoteSigned\ -windowStyle\ Normal\ -Command
:set shell='C:\\windows\\SysWOW64\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe'
:set shellxquote=
```

But when I do it runs it like this:

Then I'll run a command like `!ls` and get this output:

```
'C:\windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -NoProfile -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -windowStyle Normal -Command "ls"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

(note the quotes around the powershell path)

What variable causes those quotes to be there?  It is keeping me from running my command.

Comment: I think you missed some output after your sentence `But when I do it runs it like this:`

Comment: @statox no that isn’t it I copied and pasted just the bit between the quotes.

Comment: Is that a correct path to the `powershell.exe`?... If ya try the command (with quotes) within a terminal (without Vim) do ya get different results?... As for why there may be quotes in the output, it's because they'er _`:set`_ up that way; hint look to `shellcmdflag` for something `:set` without quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does vim call powershell surrounded by two single quotes?

For it's own protection, maybe, but more than likely someone was thinking about protection of users too; single quotes *should* mean *"don't expand this string"* where as double quotes kinda mean *"treat the output of this string as an argument"*

> What variable causes those quotes to be there?

The `shell` variable that has been `:set`

```
:set shell='C:\\windows\\SysWOW64\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe'
```

... without quotes might look like...

```
:set shell=C:\\windows\\SysWOW64\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe
```

> It is keeping me from running my command.

I'd suggest double-checking that file path, including double-checking capitalization, because it might not be the quote's fault that errors be popping.

For example `windows` may be `Windows`, though if I've read the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/starting-windows-powershell?view=powershell-6) correctly one might be able to mitigate some of this by using the built in variable `%SystemRoot%`...

```
:set shell='%SystemRoot%\\SysWOW64\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe'
```

Comment: Without quotes did the trick.  I guess if the path has spaces you just have to escape them that way.

Comment: Excellent, and glad it helped... though that MS doesn't take kindly to quotes does tempt one to suggest trying out [Linux on a USB](https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/burn.html), because there's likely going to be other issues that'll arise, especially if ya one day want to use _plug-ins_ that didn't code for _non-Unix like_ devices. May seem a little _much_ just for Vim, but as it looks like ya want tighter integration with the host, Linux'll be one of the smoother routes that doesn't cost. However, if the concern is Windows then good luck with that hairline ;-)